# Import CSV data into SQL using bulk insert with text qualifier

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am looking for a solution to my task. I am importing 800 000 records in CSV format into SQL server. The data is comma separated and the text qualifier is double quotes. But some data in columns contain comma. When I tried it using SSIS package, getting the following error

> Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "xyz" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".

Therefore I googled and found one solution as Bulk Insert. The data is uploaded but with errors. The column containing comma are splitting into another columns. Below is the query.

```
BULK
INSERT [5022019]
FROM 'E:\5022019.csv'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW=2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

Can any one help me out to eliminate the splitting of text into another columns.

Comment: Start by editing the question and including destination schema and some sample data that is successfully inserted and some that isn't.

Comment: Personally, I find it kinda cool to read about "lakhs" (and "crores" [&c.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system)), but most people here won't know what you're talking about - is a lakh a kilo, or a metre, or .... whatever. Could you please edit and change to 100K?

Comment: Can you change the CSV delimiter to something that will never be in the data e.g. tilde (~)?

Comment: In sql server 2017 and up you can use [FIELDQUOTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @HoneyBadger thanks for your suggestion. I installed ms sql 2017 and that magic word FIELDQUOTE worked for me.  Sorry my late post. I got busy with the data analyis :)